# InfoWindow doesn't open correctly with link when marker is outside view on Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made a map with markers clustered on Google Maps. The makers have a listener that set the zoom, then center the map and then open a infowindow.

In a for loop I made a list with links to every marker that looks like this

```
<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markers['+i+'],\'click\');">' + item.nombre + '</a>
```

If I click a marker on the map there is no problem: the map is centered and the infowindow is showed.

The problem is if I press a link form the list: if the maker is not showing on the map the infowindow is open incorrectly (in a wrong position and overlapping an icon) and the map is not centered (the map doesn't even show the correct place of the marker).
[image: like this]

Strangely, if I zoom out the map at a point that the real position of the marker is showed the InfoWindow is set correctly on the correct marker and there is no problem if I press the same link again, just like in the second image.

[image: No problem]

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feandoe/avn2cxwh/1/), the error could be reproduced if I click on *Playa Maqui Lodge* and then on any other link using Firefox 43

So, what am I missing? Why the map is not centering on the link?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined`

Comment: question updated! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker isn't added to the map until it is "unclustered", zoom to it then "click" on it.  The zoom must be higher than the maxZoom of the markerClusterer.

Either [set the markerClusterer maxZoom to 15](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ercfmsb1/2/) or change your code to zoom in closer to the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.close();
  map.setZoom(21);
  map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
  infowindow.setContent(this.html);
  infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ercfmsb1/2/)

Looks like there is an issue with the computation of the anchor using a custom infowindow (which I didn't see before as you didn't provide your custom marker).  It works if you don't use the `InfoWindow.open(map, anchor)` syntax and set the `pixelOffset` and `position` of the InfoWindow manually.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(0,-35)});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.close();
  map.setZoom(16);
  map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
  infowindow.setContent(this.html);
  infowindow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```

[updated proof of concept fiddle (with custom marker)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/avn2cxwh/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just copy your code on jsFiddle and add more markers and the error persist. I just updated the question with the link to the jsFiddle with the issue